# Toggle Button is checked automatically at runtime when back to fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I have 2 Fragments.

**FirstFragment** has only a button. When user press the button, the **SecondFragment** is shown.

Both fragments are in backstack. So, when **SecondFragment** is shown, if user press physical back button, the **FirstFragment** will be shown.

Everything works fine at this point.

Now, on **SecondFragment** layout, I added an `ToggleButton`:

```
<ToggleButton 
    android:id="@+id/my_toggle"
    android:checked="false"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOn="@string/on"
        android:textOff="@string/off"
/>
```

My **SecondFragment.java** :

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment{

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle){
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

   //My Toggle Button
    myToggleBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
       new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){

            Log.v("*TOGGLE CHECK CHANGED*",String.valueOf(isChecked));

            if(isChecked){
                //DO SOME THING 

            }else{  
                //DO SOMETHING ELSE     
            }
           }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_layout, null);
    }
 ...

 @Override
 public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    //Set my toggle button to unchecked status,when leave this fragment 
    myToggleBtn.setChecked(false);
  }

}
```

The toggle button works fine on my **SecondFragment**. **BUT**, if now I press the toggle button to check it(so it changed to checked status), then press physical back button to go back to FirstFragment (onDestroy() is called which set toggle button to unchecked status) , and then come to SecondFragment again, **surprisingly**, at this moment, the `ToggleButton` is checked at run time, and I noticed from LogCat, the `OnCheckedChangeListener()` is invoked at run time too, why?

P.S.: LogCat shows that onDestroy() is called when leaving SecondFragment

Comment: Did you check if `onDestroy()` is called when you leave `SecondFragment`?

Comment: Yes, onDestroy() is called when leave SecondFragment.

Comment: how and where is `myToggleBtn` declared and initialized?

Comment: In second fragment, add logging (or set breakpoint) at `onCreateView)()` and check if `savedInstanceState` is null or non-null. If non-null, then the second fragment is being "restored" to its earlier saved state. I assume that the saved state has the state of the toggle button as "checked" because I would assume that by the time `onDestroy()` is called in the fragment it is too late to change the state of the toggle button.

Comment: @ David , then how can I reset the toggle button to unchecked when leaving the fragment?

Comment: You could try to override `onSaveInstanceState` and call `myToggleBtn.setChecked(false);` there.

Comment: I checked that onSaveInstanceState is null. So, what @ David said is not the reason of my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I moved `myToggleBtn.setChecked(false);` from `onDestroy()` to `onStop()`, the problem get solved. Thanks.